# Arrays within arrays in a plist

Tags: xcode, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

I am really struggling on this one; I have read many different posts and the apple literature but to no avail.  I have the following plist in my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>7A</key>
<dict>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Cells</string>
    <key>Subunits</key>
    <array>
        <string>Some</string>
        <string>Text</string>
        <string>In</string>
        <string>Here</string>
    </array>
</dict>
<key>7B</key>
<dict>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Reproduction</string>
    <key>Subunits</key>
    <array>
        <string>Different</string>
        <string>Text</string>
        <string>In</string>
        <string>Here</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

In the tableview that I have, I can display the 7A and 7B by using an array to hold "allKeys".  The problem I am facing now is what to do when clicked.  I've used a property to pass to the next viewcontroller the selected cell as a string and the original dictionary.  However, I can't seem to "drill down" to the Subunits array.
 Any help would be much appreciated.
 Many thanks.

Comment: Apologies... I missed off another </dict> and </plist> at the end by accident!  Question still stands though... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary* dict;   // as loaded from your plist file
NSString* selectedKey = @"7A";
NSDictionary* subDict = [dict objectForKey:selectedKey];
NSArray* subunits = [subDict objectForKey:@"Subunits"];
```

Then `subunits` should be an array of NSStrings.